# How can I check if cordova is ready if the deviceready event has already fired?

Tags: javascript, events, cordova, ready

In the example app cordova provides through `cordova create ...`, the following code listens to the `deviceready` event:

```
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
```

This is nice, but what happens when the event is fired before I've had time to listen for it? As an example, replace the code from the example app (above) with the following:

```
bindEvents: function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    }, 2000)
},
```

In this example, this.onDeviceReady is never called. Would there not be a better, more reliable way to check if cordova is ready? Something like this:

```
bindEvents: function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (window.cordovaIsReady) {
            this.onDeviceReady()
        } else {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        }
    }, 2000)
},
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As per the cordova documentation

> The deviceready event behaves somewhat differently from others.  Any
>   event handler registered after the deviceready event fires has its
>   callback function called immediately.

As you can see if any event Handler is attached **AFTER** the deviceready has fired it will be called **immediately**.
In a **setTimeout** function **this** is a no longer pointing to the intended object, the context is different. Therefore your handler will never be called.
You can try the below code by placing it in your `<head>` tag, where I am using global functions/variables (avoiding the **this** context issues for sake of simplicity). This should show you an alert.

```
<script>
    function onDeviceReady () {
     alert("Calling onDeviceReady()");
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    }, 9000);
</script>
```

Comment: Right you are. I had totally misinterpreted the issue here.

Answer (score -1):

`frank` answer really works. But the right way to handle this is not by adding timeout.

The `deviceready` Event Handler will be created while DOM is loading. So to use the event we should wait untill `DOMContentLoaded`. after that we can add listener to the `deviceready` event

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    //alert("Calling DOMContentLoaded");
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
        //alert("Calling onDeviceReady()");
        callFirebase();
    }, false);
});
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the accepted answer: @frank demonstrates that an event listener can be created at any time for `deviceready` - even 9 seconds after the page has loaded. So, no need to wait for any event (including `DOMContentLoaded`.)