# Cordova SQLite plugin only works on first call

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a cordova app with two pages, the first has a search field and the second displays the results of the first.
The `displayResults` function

```
function displayResults(){
    var query = localStorage.getItem('search');
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name:"Store-DB", location: 1});
    queryDB(db,query);
    }

function queryDB(db,query){
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
            var queryList = query.split(" ");
            var sqlText = "SELECT * FROM DB WHERE item LIKE '%"+queryList[0]+"%'";
            for (i = 1; i < queryList.length; i++) {
                    sqlText += " OR item LIKE '%"+queryList[i]+"%'";
            }
            tx.executeSql(sqlText, [], querySuccess);
        }
        );
    }

function querySuccess(tx,results) {
    var i;
    var len = results.rows.length;
    //Iterate through the results
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        console.log(row);
        //Get the current row
        var row = results.rows.item(i);
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.background = "gray";
        div.style.color = "white";
        div.innerHTML = row;

        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
    alert("Finished");
}
```

Here is the code for the second page:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/zepto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="plugins/com.brodysoft.sqlitePlugin/www/SQLitePlugin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/code.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onLoad(){
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);
        }
        function onDeviceReady(){
            displayResults();
        }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
        <div id="taskbar">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a id="username" class="toolbar_item" style="float:right;"  href="#"></a>
        </div>
```

The first time you load this page `displayResults` works just fine, but if you click the link back to the main page and load the second page again the console prints the error `ReferenceError: no "undefined" has no property "openDatabase"` in other words, the SQLite plugin isn't loading. But, if I make `displayResults` fire on a button press instead of `onload` it works every time. What is the explanation for this peculiar behavior?

Comment: a reason could be that onload is fired too early before this plugin is loaded fully. I only read about such bug in ionic-framework but this could be a reason as well here.

Comment: @Blauharley Yes, that is almost definitely the issue, I knew that, but how do I fix it? I.E. How do I not fire the event until the plugins are loaded?

Comment: I'm seeing your cordova.js script is above brodysoft-plugin script, it is worth a try to switch their positions. It is recommended to put cordova.js on the bottom of a page-file

Comment: @Blauharley Nope, then I get `cordova not defined`

Comment: Did you try out this answer here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341826/how-can-i-check-if-cordova-is-ready-if-the-deviceready-event-has-already-fired so settimeout might help.

Comment: @Blauharley That worked, mind putting that as the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It's actually a hack but you are welcome ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that sometimes deviceready-event is either not fired at all or fired too early when there are more event handlers of different libraries in place. The second problem caused that the brodysoft-plugin is not loaded properly and assign to the window-object as window.sqlitePlugin property because one event handler dispatched deviceready-event too early. It turned out setTimeout was the answer as it had been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341826/how-can-i-check-if-cordova-is-ready-if-the-deviceready-event-has-already-fired)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onpageshow event for example

```
$('#idofyourpage').bind("onpageshow",function(){
   //Do something
});
```